# Getting `attempt to index local 'err_msg'` when using luaunit

Tags: unit-testing, lua

When using luaunit for Lua unit testing, I get the following error:

`./luaunit.lua:503: attempt to index local 'err_msg' (a nil value)`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code-under-test does not override the `debug` built-in variable. That would cause that error.